# Getting access token Uber API

Tags: uber-api

Im having trouble getting my access token from the uber API.

I get a code back from your server when I click login with uber-

I then put this into my headers in insomnia
.

```
grant_type:authorization_code (i just type 'authorization_code' here)

code: 0RWlkekK3kXdoKSDlbSuI6HAZHbb0K ( i know this expires after 10 mins but i have tried with different codes )

redirect_uri:http://localhost:3000/auth/uber/callback (the redirect i have on your app)

client_id:my_client_id (whatever it is in manage my app)

client_secret:my_client_secret
```

But i do not get a response from your server with my token.

What am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Can you provide the error that you receive from the server?

Comment: when i make a post request to  https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token I get this error message 'Could not reach     https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token'

Comment: @Alec Any news on this ?  Am i doing the post request right to get a response from the API?

Answer (score 0):

If you give Uber `localhost` in your URI it will be trying to connect to itself, not back to your server.  Use a hostname or IP address that is valid on the open Internet.

Answer (score 0):

1. redirect_uri should exactly the same as the one you put on your dashboard.
2. the code may expire or been consumed (AngularJs $location redirection will make it expire for some reason)
3. Post the data body may need to jQuery: $.param(data) or AngularJs: $httpParamSerializer(data)